# Убрать из автоимпортов библиотеку AWT (Intelij)

Tags: intellij-idea

Каждый раз, когда я, например, объявляю список:

```
List<Elements> listName;
```

И нажимаю Alt-Enter, чтобы импортировать зависимость - появляется несколько вариантов:

- `java.awt.list`
- `java.util.list`

Причем `java.awt.list` я никогда не использую, но он все равно сверху. Это неудобно. Как можно убрать его из выпадающего списка?

Comment: Минус наверное поставил вкладчик в МММ

Comment: А java.util.List он не предлагает? Если нет, значит jdk не подключён. Комментируйте по делу.

Comment: Я нормальный вопрос спросил вообщето!!!

Comment: Я не про вопрос, а про комментарий.

Comment: @NikolaySobyanin например, лично мне суть этого вопроса интересна, но вот его оформление расстраивает. Если вопрос сделать, не знаю, более культурным, то результат вполне может быть другим

Comment: Для Intellij IDEA [такое находится](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700292/3432401), для Eclipse - [такое](https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/eclipse-ide-get-rid-of-the-javaawtlist-proposal-in-organize-imports.html). Для NetBeans, которым часто пользуюсь, увы, ничего так сходу найти не удалось

Comment: Вам не библиотека мешает, а то, что вы не можете сами нормально импортировать зависимость.

Answer (score 1):

В IntelliJ из автоимпорта можно исключить отдельные пакеты:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Auto Import` > `Java` > `Exclude from Import and Completion`.

По этому пути добавляем в список `javax.awt` (удобно, также, `javax.swing`).

Больше подробностей Вы можете найти в [IntelliJ manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/excluding-classes-from-auto-import.html#r_Excluding_Classes_from_Auto-Import.xmld235936e72).

Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700292/12404171)